# How to print to USB printer connected to AirportExtreme via ethernet port?

Tags: network, wifi, airport, printing

I have a AirportExtreme router and a new AT&T Fiber router that comes with faster Wi-Fi.

```
AT&T router <--ethernet-- AirportExtreme <--USB-- USB printer
            <--Wi-Fi-- MacBook
```

I'd like to print to the USB printer from my mac via the AT&T Wi-Fi router and Airport Extreme. Is there any way to do this? Currently, I switch to AirportExtreme Wi-Fi to print something, then switch back to AT&T router for faster connection speed. I feel computers connected to AirportExtreme's ethernet should be able to print to the printer too, but i'm not able to set this up. Please advise.

My AT&T router doesn't support USB printers, unfortunately.

Comment: I don’t understand why you’re switching.  Both the Mac and the APE are on the same network.  Why are you using the APE anyway?

Comment: If you put your Airport Extreme in "Bridge Mode" it will stop acting like another router and become part of the network set up by the ATT router. Then you won't have to switch networks and the Airport becomes just another device on your network and will still host the Printer across the network. Sorry to be so short on details. I don't have one anymore and only vaguely recall the terminology and details.